# How do I know if a server supports SSL?

Tags: java, ssl, tcp

I need to connect to a host, if it's off-line I get a TCP timeout (and it's ok), and if it's online with SSL available, I proceed to the logon phase.

The problem is, when the server is online, accepts connection on the configured TCP port, but then doesn't answer to SSL handshake, our application waits indefinitely for an answer.

I'm using IBM HACL (c++) wrapped by JNI to access the server.

How could I test (in Java or C++ under Windows XP) the availability of SSL on the server side? Can I start a handshake manually, get the first server response, and then close the TCP socket? Or do I need to complete the handshake (and how do I?)

Thanks.

Comment: hm, actually, how about providing some of the code there.. Because in normal environment the connection drops immediately.

Comment: Create a server socket, and let it listen on a port without sending anything, then try to connect to that port, and start the SSL handshake.

I tried it with netcat.

Comment: ECLConnList ConnList;
ECLConnection *Conn = ConnList.GetFirstConnection();
Conn->StartCommunication();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getDefault();
    ctx.getClientSessionContext().setSessionTimeout(5); // in seconds
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) 
         ctx.getSocketFactory().createSocket("host.com", 443);

    socket.setSoTimeout(5000); // in millis
    socket.startHandshake();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    sslAvailable = false;
}
```

As per your comment the `socket.setSoTimeout(5000)` did the trick.

If that doesn't work, then:

```
URLConnection urlConn = // obtain connection
urlConn.setConnectTimeout(5000); // in millis
```

Comment: Uhm, works, but it seems to do exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to do:

- If the host doesn't answer at all, startHandshake() waits forever. I could wrap that in a thread and close the socket after a given timeout.

- If the host supports SSL, I get a javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

It could work, but I don't know if it's the right solution.

Comment: Same problem. Session timeout is something different.

Comment: Found the solution: it's not "setSessionTimeout" on the context, it's "setSoTimeout" on the socket.

Comment: good. I'll include it in the answer above so that it's more visible to others with the same problem

Answer (score 2):

In SSL, the first message to be sent is always by the client: a ClientHello.  The server should response with a ServerHello message, so that'll be when you know it supports SSL.  You can close the connection (by sending a close_notify alert) at *any* point.  **You do not need to complete the handshake**.

Iit is quite common for peers to terminate mid-handshake if the session parameters do not allow a trusted session be established.

In Java, the [SSLEngine](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html) class gives you the sort of control you desire over the SSL handshake, but it is quite a complex state machine requiring in-depth knowledge of SSL.

Comment: Good to know that there's a solution, at least in theory.
I just need to find out how to implement that in Java.

Comment: Create an SSLSocket and either call startHandshake() or send some data. If you don't do either of those things the handshake doesn't start. Set a socket timeout as well just to be sure.

Comment: @EJP: Good to see you on here.  I enjoyed your networking book. :)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, when the server is
>   online, accepts connection on the
>   configured TCP port, but then doesn't
>   answer to SSL handshake, our
>   application waits indefinitely for an
>   answer.

As general purpose solution why not put the connect code into a thread and waiting for the thread until a timeout is reached.

Comment: Yes, we did: the connection hangs and can't be closed.
The problem is the IBM Host Access Library.

Comment: As a general purpose solution why not just use a read timeout?